# Monetary transactions in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I plan to have a collection called `transactions` where I want to store all the monetary transactions between users. Before making a `transaction` I want to be sure that the `sender` has enough money in his account.

For the account balance I plan to calculate on demand and not have it stored.

Is there a pattern I can use in MongoDB to avoid race conditions?

Ie. let's say user A has a balance of $10. If he makes two send requests of $10 at the same time I may end up with a negative in his account. Is there a way to avoid that?

Comment: Actually, never mind. I found this recipe in CouchDB that will work perfectly with MongoDB too: http://blog.codekills.net/2014/03/13/atomic-bank-balance-transfer-with-couchdb/

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB doesn't handles transactions like relational databases. In order to handle these transactions, I would suggest using **[Two Phase commits](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/perform-two-phase-commits/#background)**. You can even add a rollback like functionality using this.

Check out [this](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/perform-two-phase-commits/#pattern) beautiful article on the MongoDB docs on how to add two phase commits pattern.

Comment: The two phase commit would work if I kept the balance of the accounts in a document, but I don't plan to.